# Fail to connect to mongo Atlas

Tags: macos, mongodb

In order to connect via the mongo shell, the [docs](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/connect-to-cluster/) says to download a *.tgz file.

So I downloaded the shell file `mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.2.9`, unzipped it, clicked on the /bin/mongo icon in the mac finder, which opened a shell but with error:

```
~$/Users/abcdef/Downloads/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.2.9/bin/mongo ; exit;
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
connecting to: test
2016-09-29T01:06:38.656+1000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2016-09-29T01:06:38.656+1000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

`$meteor mongo` reports `MongoDB shell version 3.2.6`
`$mongo --version` reports `MongoDB shell version 3.0.12`

The reason for this question is to run MongoDB 3.2.6 with TLS/SSL support. Any idea? Thanks

**edit**
[image]

**edit 2**
After the recursive chmod suggested in the comments which fixed on problem. Now the second problem which is, I am not able to log in to The Atlas cluster.

```js
/$mongo "mongodb://cluster0-shard...shard-0" --ssl --username *** --password ***
```

> Error parsing command line: unknown option ssl

But when I use the file downloaded from mongo as stated at the start of this post. it opens a mongo shell fine. How to login to my Atlas cluster?

Do I type the command suggested by mongo Atlas on the bash terminal or the mongo shell?

Comment: Do you have write access to the /data/db folder? The default data path of mongodb is /data/db

Comment: @4J41 Where is it located so that I can check? I just finished using homebrew to install mongo and did the chmod 777 /data/db but would like to check now that you asked.

Comment: Are you able to run mongod now, after the chmod?

Comment: @4J41 No. I must add that I did the installation while I was logged as admin, but now I am logged as a user to this mac machine. I confirm that I have 777 permission on /data/db

Comment: Please set the chmod, then try to run mongod. If there aren't any other issues, it should start listening for connections. Leave mongod running and then run mongo. This will open the mongo shell.

Comment: @4J41 Please see edit where it shows 777 permission. but the error is still not allowing to run mongod

Comment: what error you getting after running mongod ?

Comment: If the there is a mongod.lock file in the /data/db folder, please remove it and run mongod.

Comment: @Pawan exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating

Comment: @4J41 after removing mongod.lock and running mongod, I get "couldn't open file /data/db/journal/tempLatencyTest for writing errno:13 Permission denied; returning false" and "13516 couldn't open file /data/db/journal/j._0 for writing errno:13 Permission denied, terminating
"

Comment: Please make sure to change chmod to the sub directories too. recursive chmod on /data/db.

Comment: @4J41 yes. that fixed it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command and then try to run mongod which will start mongodb server

```
sudo chown -R $USER /data/db
```

Once mongo server is up then connect to shell using mongo.

And if you want the directory to be owned by particular user or group you can do this using

```
sudo chown -R username:groupname /data/db

for e.g sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /data/db
```

the specified user should be present other wise it will give you below error

```
chown: invalid user: 'mongodb:mongodb'
```

Comment: <username> is not in the sudoers file. Thus I re-logged in as admin user and chmod -R 777 /data/db as suggested by 4j41.

Answer (score 0):

> error:NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor-0] Successfully connected to cluster

The problem is your mongo client version.
You have to updade to Mongo 3.4 with suport SSL

Comment: Your answer would benefit from more explanation.